# Jenkins pipeline - how to make wait between parallel running

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, parallels

I want to run 3 tests in parallel,but, I want the 2nd test to start running 5 seconds after the 1st test, and the 3rd test to start 5 seconds after the 2nd test.

Is it possible?

Comment: can you elaborate ? some code ,is each test is run command line or new job ?

Comment: Similar question answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73146768/how-to-make-wait-between-jenkins-parallel-job-in-groovy

Answer (score 1):

Give a example of Declarative Pipeline

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {

        stage("Test") {
            steps {
                script {

                    parallel(
                        DEV: {
                            sleep 5
                            echo 'DEV'
                        },                             

                        QA: {
                            sleep 6
                            echo 'QA'
                        }
                    )
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Similar answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73146768/how-to-make-wait-between-jenkins-parallel-job-in-groovy