# How to make wait between jenkins parallel job in groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I have tried below things to make wait between parallel job in jenkins using groovy script but its not waiting.

```
def jobs = [:]                                                                        
 for(int i=1;i<=5;i++)
 {
    def component = i
    jobs[component] = 
    {   
      sleep(i) {
      echo "Waiting for ${i} seconds"
      }                                             
    }
 }
 parallel jobs
```

am i missing something or its totally wrong i couldn't figure out

Thanks

Comment: In your case your sleep is inside each parallel block.
Please explain what do you mean by "Wait" wait before what?

Comment: wait before starting next job. here i have given wait inside parallel block so it should increase the wait time for next job as it has value of "i" variable. @Barelelbaz

Comment: Your code will trigger 5 components at the same time, and inside each of them it will sleep i seconds.
but the triggering time is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All parallel blocks will start in the same time but each one will sleep "i" seconds before the actual logic execution (Echo command will be executed "i" seconds after the "parallel" call).

Please try:

```
def jobs = [:]                                                                        
 for(int i=1;i<=5;i++)
 {
    def component = i
    jobs[component] = 
    {   
      sleep(i)
      echo "Waiting for ${i} seconds"                                     
    }
 }
 parallel jobs
```

`sleep` step does not get Closue as parameter...